# R: What's the R equivalent to numpy's .dtype.itemsize and .dtype.alignment array properties?

Tags: python, r, equivalent, justify

I'm trying to convert something like this from python into R:

```
dt = my_array.dtype
fw = int(dt.itemsize/dt.alignment)
b = numpy.array([list(w.ljust(fw)) for w in my_array.T])
```

I've looked around but haven't found anything on this particular topic.

Comment: Not every R person know Python, so explaining what this is doing might attract more answers. Is this for formatting numeric output on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line extracts the data type. R might use class(my_array). Using typeof or mode might also be possible but unless you have studied R for a while you may not get the information you desire. It appears that Python encodes several types of information in the datatype string. There isn't really an exact parallel in R but you might want to look at the value returned by str(). Unlike Python's `dt`, the value from `str` is not going to be accessible for further breaks=down by additional functions. From its help page:

> Value
>
> str does not return anything, for efficiency reasons. The obvious side effect is output to the terminal.

The `attributes` function will sometimes yield additional information about an object, but in the case of an array there's nothing additional to the information from `dim`.

```
> my_array <- array(1:24, c(2,3,4))  # a 2 x 3 x 4 array of integers
> class(my_array)
[1] "array"
> str(my_array)
 int [1:2, 1:3, 1:4] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
dim(my_array)   # Not sure, but this might be the equivalent of "alignment"
[1] 2 3 4
 attributes(my_array)
$dim
[1] 2 3 4
> length(my_array)
[1] 24
> mode(my_array)
[1] "numeric"
```